# i have a problem showing the json data in the drop-down list flutter

Tags: json, flutter

this is my first flutter JSON example, I tried to fetch data from the JSON link and display it on a drop-down list.

I am getting the response on the console but the drop-down list doesn't work

any help, please?......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

[this is the body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1W5o.png)

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez79x.png)

this is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _getfamilyList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 5),
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      alignedDropdown: true,
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        value: _myfamily,
                        iconSize: 30,
                        icon: (null),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                        hint: Text('Select family'),
                        onChanged: (String newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _myfamily = newValue;

                            print(_myfamily);
                          });
                        },
                        items: familysList?.map((item) {
                              return new DropdownMenuItem(
                                child: new Text(item['firsName']),
                              );
                            })?.toList() ??
                            [],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
   

      
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  List familysList;
  String _myfamily;
  String familyInfoUrl =
      'http://10.0.2.2:3000/genocheck/user/getmembrefamille/f1';
  Future<String> _getfamilyList() async {
    await http.get(familyInfoUrl).then((response) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);

      print(data);
      setState(() {
        familysList = data['famille'];
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I see the problem is in your JSON response

famille is the first element ,
the list of data is the second element

however in your code  `familysList = data['famille'];`

you are assuming that famille is a key and the list of data is the value and this is not correct

so answer is one of those

1 - make your asignment like `familysList = data[0];`

2- change your json to be `{"famille" :[{"id":8654,"firstname":"some name"]"}`

Comment: i changed the response to this  
{
    "response": [
        {
            "_id": "6078278c8c52913c40de89a2",
            "firstName": "bilel"
        },
    ]
}
Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state: _MyHomePageState#25e19):
type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>?'

The relevant error-causing widget was
MyHomePage
package:flutter_genocheck_1/frompages/Api.dart:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

Answer (score 0):

The error caused because although data's type is List that can access by 'int' index, you access like Map.

```
data['famille']
```

As your data body, data[0] is 'famille' and data[1] is data what you want.

data[1] is

```
[ 
    {
        "_id": "",
        "firstName": "",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: `data[0]` is `String famille`, `data[1]` is `List` you want

```
familysList = data[1];
```

Step 2: `firsName` is typo you need `firstName` 
Step 3: `DropdownMenuItem` need `value` attribute

```
items: familysList?.map((item) {             
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text("${item["firstName"]}"),
            value: item["firstName"],
          );
        })?.toList() ??
```

working demo

[image]

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _getfamilyList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 5),
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      alignedDropdown: true,
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        value: _myfamily,
                        iconSize: 30,
                        icon: (null),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                        hint: Text('Select family'),
                        onChanged: (String Value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _myfamily = Value;

                            print("_myfamily $_myfamily");
                          });
                        },
                        items: familysList?.map((item) {
                              //print(item["firstName"]);
                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                child: Text("${item["firstName"]}"),
                                value: item["firstName"],
                              );
                            })?.toList() ??
                            [],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List familysList;
  String _myfamily;
  String familyInfoUrl =
      'http://10.0.2.2:3000/genocheck/user/getmembrefamille/f1';

  Future<String> _getfamilyList() async {
    String jsonString = '''
    [
  "famille",
  [
     {
       "_id" : "123",
       "firstName":"abc"
     },
     {
       "_id" : "456",
       "firstName":"def"
     }
  ] 
]
    ''';

    http.Response response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(data);

    setState(() {
      familysList = data[1];
    });

    /*await http.get(familyInfoUrl).then((response) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);

      print(data);
      setState(() {
        familysList = data[1];
      });
    });*/
  }
}
```

full code 2 for new question

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class UserElement {
  UserElement({
    this.id,
    this.firstName,
  });

  String id;
  String firstName;

  factory UserElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserElement(
        id: json["_id"] == null ? null : json["_id"],
        firstName: json["firstName"] == null ? null : json["firstName"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id == null ? null : id,
        "firstName": firstName == null ? null : firstName,
      };
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _getfamilyList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 5),
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      alignedDropdown: true,
                      child: DropdownButton<UserElement>(
                        value: _myfamily,
                        iconSize: 30,
                        icon: (null),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                        hint: Text('Select family'),
                        onChanged: (UserElement Value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _myfamily = Value;

                            print("_myfamily ${_myfamily.firstName}");
                          });
                        },
                        items: familysList?.map((item) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<UserElement>(
                                child: Text("${item.id} ${item.firstName}"),
                                value: item,
                              );
                            })?.toList() ??
                            [],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<UserElement> familysList = [];
  UserElement _myfamily;
  String familyInfoUrl =
      'http://10.0.2.2:3000/genocheck/user/getmembrefamille/f1';

  Future<String> _getfamilyList() async {
    String jsonString = '''
    [
  "famille",
  [
     {
       "_id" : "123",
       "firstName":"abc"
     },
     {
       "_id" : "456",
       "firstName":"abc"
     }
  ] 
]
    ''';

    http.Response response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    //print(data);

    setState(() {
      List<dynamic> listData = data[1];
      for (var i = 0; i < listData.length; i++) {
        familysList.add(UserElement.fromJson(listData[i]));
      }
    });

    /*await http.get(familyInfoUrl).then((response) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);

      print(data);
      setState(() {
        familysList = data['famille'];
      });
    });*/
  }
}
```

Comment: i need to show the json response in the drop down list

Comment: @BilelDhouibi, sorry I do not known what you mean, example code has show first name.

Comment: in your code the first name is in json String that you created and in my case, I need the first name from the response

Comment: example code is only for simulate your error, you can follow step and change your code  follow Step 1 to Step3

Comment: @BilelDhouibi, you can unmark await http.get in the example code. and remark my code.

Comment: thanks a lot, it was very helpful, but  i got one more problem i have the same first name in the database so when I pick that name the console through me an error if have time to answer me I will be grateful

Comment: You can use Model , please see full code 2 and gif